# FBSDKAppInviteDialog always shows red ! mark when trying to invite

Tags: ios, facebook-sdk-4.0

just upgraded to the new Facebook SDK iOS and trying to implement the FBSDKAppInviteDialog.

Unfortunately every time I try to invite someone it does this[image]

anyone knows how to fix or debug this?

Comment: Can you try again please? What applink are you using, the one generated by Facebook tool?

Comment: i reported a bug to facebook and it seems valid - here the link https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1404511886531563